# Event Handling Help for JavaFx-8 (Home Screen Attached to Login Screen) can't get home buttons to work

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx-8, scenebuilder

Hello I have designed and programmed the game and I'm almost done i'm just having a small problem connecting my model & action events.

1) I cant get my action event method to coordinate with my quit or close button which resides on the Home Page.
2) I'm just trying to also connect the methods in my model to connect to my action events in my controller also.
3) I just need a short example on what I'm doing wrong...

this is my loginController:

```
 @FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {


    System.out.println("Login Now");
    Parent home_page_parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLHomePage.fxml"));
    Scene home_page_scene = new Scene(home_page_parent);
    String css = BlackJackFx.class.getResource("view/homePage.css").toExternalForm();
    home_page_scene.getStylesheets().add(css);
    Stage app_stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

    if (isValidCredentials())
        {
           app_stage.hide();
           app_stage.setScene(home_page_scene);
           app_stage.show();
        }
    else
        {
          username_box.clear();
          password_box.clear();
          invalid_label.setText("Invalid Username or Password! ");
        }

}

private boolean isValidCredentials()
{
    boolean let_in = false;
    System.out.println("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE USERNAME= " + "'" + username_box.getText() + "'"
        + "AND PASSWORD= " + "'" + password_box.getText() + "'");

    Connection c = null;
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
    try{
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:BjFx.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);

        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        stmt = c.createStatement();

         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE USERNAME= " + "'" + username_box.getText() + "'"
        + " AND PASSWORD= " + "'" + password_box.getText() + "'");

        while ( rs.next() ) {
             if (rs.getString("USERNAME") != null && rs.getString("PASSWORD") != null) { 
                 String  username = rs.getString("USERNAME");
                 System.out.println( "USERNAME = " + username );
                 String password = rs.getString("PASSWORD");
                 System.out.println("PASSWORD = " + password);
                 let_in = true;
            }
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("isValidCredentials Operation done successfully");
        return let_in;

}      

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

}
```

and my homePageController:

```
public class FXMLHomePageController implements Initializable {

  @FXML
  private Button newGameBtn;

  @FXML
  private Button stayBtn;

  @FXML
  private Button hitBtn;

  @FXML
  private Button dblDownBtn;

  @FXML
  private Button tenBetBtn;

  @FXML
  private Button fiftyBetBtn;

  @FXML
  private Button houndredBetBtn;


  @FXML 
  private Button quitBtn;  

  @Override
   public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


   }

@FXML
public void quitBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {
Stage stage = (Stage) quitBtn.getScene().getWindow();
stage.close();
}

@FXML
public void newGameBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {
}
@FXML
public void stayBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
public void hitBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

}
@FXML
public void dblDownBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

}
@FXML
public void tenBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

}
@FXML
public void fiftyBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

}
@FXML
public void houndredBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {

}


}
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: So what happens when you press the `quitBtn`?

Comment: @James_D absolutely nothing. I click it and no action at all. I know it's probably the smallest thing but the sooner I can figure this out the sooner I can add my model to the rest of my Action event Methods...

Comment: Show the relevant FXML

Comment: @James_D <buttons>
                        <Button id="quitBtn" fx:id="quitBtn" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#quitBtnAction" onMouseClicked="#quitBtnAction" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="85.0" text="Quit" />
                     </buttons>

Comment: I know I'm gonna wake up in the morning and realize the problem and feel dumb all day.... this is the only part of learning to program I hate...

Comment: @James_D Did I show enough FXML?

Comment: @James_D I fixed it and it was just what I figured - something so simple...